# how to instal beautifulsoup on web host using BlueHost

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-hosting

i want to run a python script on a website. 
Which works fine but its telling me it cannot find the beautifulsoup module.
How can i install this?
I am using BlueHost as a provider.

here is a part of my script:

```
"""
import time
import sys

import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
"""
Above is being imported as library's 'urllib'
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with BlueHost, but can you use pip to install modules?

Comment: i got Shel acces. and i couldn't not find if i am able to use modules with Pip.

Comment: You usually can install modules in a non-system-wide fashion with the `--user` option, as in `pip install --user bs4`.

Comment: talked to the hosting provider and turned out i cannot install any modules with my current plan, as its not something i am willing to pay for i need a work around can i just include a Link on which Python will get the module from?